# which class can be used in c++ in replacement of streamtokenizer in java?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to write a program for assignment statement interpreter in c++.I have implemented the program in java.I need to tokenize the input which consists of numbers,words and operators(=,+,-,*,/).I used a stream Tokenizer in java to tokenize and parse the input.I need functions like 1.control going to next token 2.type of the current token(number or word).like functions nexttoken() and ttype() nval() sval() pushback() in java. please help me out of this.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do, as it stands, only somebody familiar with both C++ and Java could answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost::Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) is a pretty versatile tokenizer for C++ and should easily handle your case.

Comment: i saw that..but i cant find the methods like nextToken() and ttype() in that

Comment: @user864408: It's written in C++; it's not going to use the same conventions as Java. It uses iterators, which is a concept that you need to understand if you're going to use C++ for any length of time.

Comment: Are you familiar with C++ iterators? Boost::tokenizer works based on those rather than functions like nextToken(). The documentation has a good example on how to use them to extract tokens. It doesn't have a type function but you could create std::vectors of each type and then use std::find to see if it's one of them. e.g., in c++0x, `std::vector<std::string> ops = { "=", "+", "-", "*", "/" }; std::find(ops.begin(), ops.end(), tok) != ops.end(); // will return true if "tok" is an operator`